# Read Different Entries from File in Java

Tags: java

I have some problems with my code while reading the file, this is the entries of my file:

- Want
- Serious
- Try
- I Want
- I Try

and here is my code

```
//open the file 
openFile();
while(x.hasNext()){
//pass the word into variable      
    String a = x.next();
//store in array list
    Streams.add(a);
}
```

Since my entries are contains of single-word, and two-words(bigram), the script cannot read it, my script will make a word like "I want" stored in two different array, while i actually want to store the single-word and the bigram into an index.

So, the first index will contain : want, 2nd Serious, 3rd Try, 4th I want, 5th I try

Sorry for the confusing question, any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: where do you define x? can you post the entire code please?

Comment: Guessing you are using Scanner so if you wanna read a whole line each time why not use nextLine() and hasnextLine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the entries in your file present in seperate lines. If so, you could use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

Comment: never know that it will be that easy :D, thanks anyway